# MySQL query based on condition from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, not-exists

I am trying to write a MySQL query that selects 10 usernames based on a condition evaluated from another table.

The result will be 10 usernames as suggestions to follow. So, I need to select 10 usernames that are currently not being followed by the logged user.

The below returns users that are already followed, so there is something wrong with it. Any idea how to fix that ?

```
"SELECT  username
FROM    users
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  id 
        FROM    user_followers
        WHERE   user_followers.user_followed_id = users.username AND user_followers.user_follower_id = ?
        )  
ORDER BY followers DESC LIMIT 10 "
```

user_followed_id - username of user being evaluated from the outer query.
user_follower_id - username of user for which the check is made (uses prepared statements)

Comment: I think you might want to use `NOT IN` clause in place of `NOT EXISTS` and see if that works.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could update your question with table structure that you have.

Comment: `user_followers.user_followed_id = users.username`  comparing id and username? how is it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try LEFT JOIN

```
  SELECT *
  FROM users  u
  LEFT JOIN user_followers uf
    ON u.username  = uf.user_followed_id 
   AND uf.user_follower_id <> ?
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this Helps:

```
SELECT  username
FROM    users
WHERE username  NOT EXISTS
    (
    SELECT  user_followers.user_followed_id -- I see in you code below that you use this to store the username 
    FROM    user_followers
    WHERE   user_followers.user_follower_id = ?
    )
AND username <> ?  -- if the parameter is not the username,may be changed by the id column name of the user
ORDER BY followers DESC LIMIT 10
```